# Line current above conducting plane

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Question: If you have a line current in the z-axis with current I and a conducting plate parallel to it at distance d.

The magnetic field is zero inside this plate, as is for every perfect conductor, what would the magnetic field be (for every position).

Attempt:
If the plate was an infinite conducting region (from minus infinity to minus d on the x-axis) there would only be surface currents in the plane (x=-d). Given that the sum of the fields generated by the plate and line current is zero inside the plate we know the field generated by the plate, inside the plate.

If you then look at the other side of the plate at distance x from the plate the field generated by the plate must be opposite to the field inside the plate (at distance x from the plate) generated by the plate. Thus we know the field everywhere.

And if you look at the boundary conditions that describe the difference in magnetic field when traversing a surface current. (I used Griffiths Ch 5 p. 250).

This means that the difference in tangential components across a surface current is $\mu_0K$ (K the surface current) we find that for both situations the current density on the plate is equal. And given that in the first situation this current density gives the correct boundary conditions both fields must be the same.

My professor listed this as a difficult exercise.

Comment: Unless the conducting plate is ferromagnetic, it should have no effect on a magnetic field. The current in the wire would only induce currents in a conductor when it is turned on or off.

Comment: @R.W. Bird what do you mean with that? It is given in the exercise that the field is zero inside the plate.

Comment: It would appear that the author of the problem is thinking of a conductor in an electric field.

Comment: It was very explicit that the magnetic field is zero.